# p:datatable sort or filter not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to implement a sort and/or filter-function for my datatable, and I have done everything the documentation says.

The problem is, that if I klick on a sort-header or fill in a filter, nothing happens (even the ajax-symbol is not shown to i assume that nothing happens at all).

What can be the problem?

I am using:

- templates to show the p:datatable
- primefaces 5.1
- myfaces bundle 2.2.0-20131222.194304-2575.jar

code:

```
<ui:define name="content">
<h:form>
  <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{logbookProjectMembersBean.projectMembers}"  
    filterDelay="100" widgetVar="userList" emptyMessage="No ProjectMembers found with given criteria" 
    filteredValue="#{logbookProjectMembersBean.filteredProjectMembers}" rowStyleClass="#{user.enabled? 'row' : 'inactiveUserRow'}" styleClass="userList">
      <f:facet name="header">
          <p:outputPanel>
              <h:outputText>Overview</h:outputText>
              <h:outputText value="  - Search:" />
              <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('userList').filter()" style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
          </p:outputPanel>
      </f:facet>
      <p:column headerText="Name" filterBy="#{user.name}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
            <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="Surname" filterBy="#{user.surname}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
          <h:outputText value="#{user.surname}" /> 
       </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: It is a global filter. Are its getter (`getFilteredProjectMembers()`) and setter (`setFilteredProjectMembers()`) in the associated bean `LogbookProjectMembersBean` invoked? Look also for JavaScript error(s) on the browser's console, if any.

Comment: hi, you are right, it tells me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined onkeyup"

Comment: when i input on a column filter, nothing happens. when i input in the global, it tells me that the message above. both (getter and setter) are invoked by the global.

Comment: I just jouble checked it; the getter and setter is NOT called. but why?

Comment: its working, there was an error in the console, i solved it and it works

Comment: What error? What fix? You can are even encouraged to answer (and accept) your own question for others to learn